# How do I look up a second JSON data set using a variable in primary JSON - using Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I have two datasets - one defines the included items for a page, the other is a larger dataset with deeper data.  But for this lets say we have this - the first JSON data set (lets call it **page.json**)

```
{
 "title": "pageTitle here",
 "description": "Content here",
 "items": [
  {
   "id": 14,
   "name": "Bob"
  },
  {
   "id": 11,
   "name": "Dave"
  },
  {
   "id": 12,
   "name": "Fred"
  },
 ]
}
```

The second JSON data set (lets call it **data.json**) contains

```
[
 {
  "id": 14
  "name": "Bob Matthews",
  "description": "Some description here about Bob",
  "age": 24,
  "location": "Sydney"
 },
 {
  "id": 11
  "name": "Dave Smith",
  "description": "Some description here about Dave",
  "age": 23,
  "location": "Sydney"
 },
 {
  "id": 12
  "name": "Fred Williams",
  "description": "Some description here about Fred",
  "age": 42,
  "location": "Sydney"
 }
]
```

Now in my templates I have something like

```
<!-- loop through each person for this page from page.json -->
{{#each page}}
  <!-- lets find the data for this person from the data.json and display it -->
  {{#compare page.id data.id}}
   <h2>{{data.name}}</h2>
   <p>Description {{data.description}}</p>
   <p>Age {{data.age}}</p>
   <p>Location {{data.location}}
  {{/compare}}
{{/each}}
```

But this doesn't work ... is there some way **without building a custom handlebar helper** to look up (& then display data from) an item out of an array in a 2nd JSON data source?

Note: this is for a project using Assemble.io & Grunt to build static pages from JSON data sets

Thanks

Comment: i know this isn't the answer you are looking for, but you can combine the data before calling the template

Comment: Yeah not the answer I'm after, but a good idea - will look into that thanks

Comment: Silly question - I'd need to do that in the grunt.js file right? hmm

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to accomplish. I assumed this was all javascript. I use lodash, but there are other methods to merge data like that. http://jsbin.com/heqis/3/edit

Comment: Yeah it is JS, to build static pages from various json data sources with Assemble.io & Grunt

Comment: yeah, I don't think it would work unless you merge it first then

Comment: Yeah or write a custom helper - which is the conclusion I'm coming too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55614/discussion-between-shanimal-and-keranm).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but have you tried looping through the list in `data.json` to find the element that matches the current element in `page.json`. The code might need some tweeking as I've only really dealt with YAML Front Matter, and I'm not familiar with how to use the *.json files.

```
{{#each page.items}} <!-- loop through each person for this page from page.json -->
    {{#each data}}   <!-- loop through each person in list from data.json -->
        <!-- In here '../page' refers to the page in previous scope -->
        <!-- and 'this' refers to the current element in data.      --> 

        <!-- lets find the data for this person from the data.json and display it -->
        {{#compare ../page.id this.id}}
            <h2>{{this.name}}</h2>
            <p>Description {{this.description}}</p>
            <p>Age {{this.age}}</p>
            <p>Location {{this.location}}    
       {{/compare}}

    {{/each}} <!-- end data loop -->
{{/each}}     <!-- end page.items loop -->
```